# Specifying picture informant in order to read specific datetme string

Tags: datetime, sas, datetime-format, informat

I would like to read the `"19-APR-21 18.17.06.301100"` the string into a `DATETIME` and display accordingly. In order to achieve that I'm intending to define a display format and an `informat` as provided in the example below.

## Example

```
* Define formats to read and display data;
* Input format;
PROC FORMAT LIB=work;
    PICTURE indte other = '%d-%B-%y %H.%M.%S.%s'
        (DATATYPE=DATETIME);
RUN;

* Nice display format;
PROC FORMAT LIB=work;
    PICTURE outdte other = '%d %B %y %H:%M'
        (DATATYPE=DATETIME);
RUN;

* Test with sample data;
DATA text;
    strdate = "19-APR-21 18.17.06.301100";
RUN;
    
* Apply informat and display format;
DATA pretty(RENAME=(strdate=nicedte));
    SET work.text;
    ATTRIB strdate INFORMAT=indte.;
    FORMAT strdate outdte.;
RUN;
```

## Problems/questions

1. The `DATA` `pretty` procedure is not able to load the define formats and returns the following error:

   > NOTE 485-185: Informat `$INDTE` was not found or could not be loaded.
   >
   > NOTE 484-185: Format `$OUTDTE` was not found or could not be loaded.
2. Is this an efficient way of doing this for the data that in the proper process is sourced via: `infile <file ref created by filename> delimiter=',' stopover firstobs=2 dsd  lrecl=32767;`?

Comment: PICTURE is used to define formats, not informats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PICTURE is used to create a FORMAT, not an INFORMAT.

The ANYDTDTM informat should handle strings in that style.  But it will ignore the fractions of a second.

```
DATA text;
  strdate = "19-APR-21 18.17.06.301100";
  datetime = input(strdate,anydtdtm.);
  format datetime datetime26.6 ;
  put (_all_) (=/);
RUN;
```

Results:

```
strdate=19-APR-21 18.17.06.301100
datetime=19APR2021:18:17:06.000000
```

If you need the fractions of a second then parse the string and read it separately.

```
  datetime  = dhms(input(strdate,date9.)
                  ,input(scan(strdate,2,' .'),2.)
                  ,input(scan(strdate,3,' .'),2.)
                  ,input(scan(strdate,4,' .'),2.)
                  +input(scan(strdate,5,' .'),6.6)
              );
```

Comment: You can (possibly) additionally put @Tom transform into a FCMP UDF and create a custom informat based on the UDF